# Increases movement speed Image after scale

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have Image on Canvas on WinPhone application.
I can scale and translate Image use this code:

```
private void image_ManipulatioDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{

    //handle stretch and pinch gestures
    if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X != 0 && e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y != 0)
    {
        double scX = scaleImage.ScaleX * e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
        if (scX > 0)
        {
            scaleImage.ScaleX = scX;
        }
        double scY = scaleImage.ScaleY * e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;
        if (scY > 0)
        {
            scaleImage.ScaleY = scY;
        }

    }

    //handle pan gesture

    translateImage.X += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X;
    translateImage.Y += e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.Y;
}
```

but after pinch Image movement speed increase.
after stretch Image movement speed decrease.

How make movement speed independent from size image?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing the speed change is relative to the scaling. Maybe try dividing the translation variables by the scale factor. Something like:
`translateImage.X += ( e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X / scaleImage.ScaleX);`

Comment: Paddyd, thanks.                                                       I tried it, but I has same behavior.

Comment: need use following formula: translateImage.X += ( e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X * scaleImage.ScaleX);

Comment: Do you have it working as you wanted?

Comment: translateImage.X += ( e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X * scaleImage.ScaleX); - it is working fine

Comment: Accept the answer If it satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Adding answer for anybody who has the same problem in the future.**

As the Image changes size, the pinch movement speed increases or decreases along with it.
To compensate for this and get the image to constantly move at the same speed, the amount the image translates by needs to be modified relative to the scaling.

I suggested dividing the translation by the scale factor `scaleImage.ScaleX`

```
translateImage.X += ( e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X / scaleImage.ScaleX);
```

OP found the solution by tweaking this and multiplying by `scaleImage.ScaleX` which gave the desired result:

```
translateImage.X += ( e.DeltaManipulation.Translation.X * scaleImage.ScaleX);
```